# How to convert wcf http web service to https

Tags: web-services, wcf, http, https, webservice-client

I have built an http based web service application with WCF and everything works. Now I try to convert it to run over https instead, but I can’t get it to work properly. I only receive "Bad Request". Currently this web service is running on IIS 7.5 and .NET 4.5. Anyone knows what i shall do to convert it from http to https and what I shall change on client side to be able to request an https web service instead of http.

Thx in advanced!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/f75fcdfd-4e2e-43d6-9654-5b858b41b5a5/conversion-of-wcf-to-https-from-http?forum=silverlightweb And http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi

Answer (score 0):

For Services Configuration use this

```
<services>
<service behaviorConfiguration="webServiceClientBehavior" name="My.Service.ServiceName">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/WCFClient"  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding" contract="My.Service.IServiceName"/>
</service>
```

For Binding Configuration use below

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureBinding">
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

For behavior configuration use below

```
 <serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior name="webServiceClientBehavior">
      <!--For MetaData-->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost/WCFClientMD"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
```